# How can I sort and get a list in complex collection mongodb in java?

Tags: java, mongodb

This is my dbcollection  in mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "name" : "+Anima",
    "author" : "MUKAI Natsumi",
    "type" : [ 
        "Adventure", 
        "Fantasy"
    ],
    "chapters" : [ 
        {
            "chapterName" : "+Anima 56",
            "chapterLink" : "http://...",
            "groupTranslate" : "Manga Palace Group",
            "dateUpload" : 1359478800000,
            "chapterNumber" : 56.0000000000000000,
            "images" : [ 
                 "img0", 
                "img1", 
                "img2", 
                "img3"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "chapterName" : "+Anima 55",
            "chapterLink" : "http://....",
            "groupTranslate" : "Manga Palace Group",
            "dateUpload" : 1410109200000,
            "chapterNumber" : 55.0000000000000000,
            "images" : [ 
                "img0", 
                "img1", 
                "img2", 
                "img3"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I cannot find list chapter sort by "dateUpload" in mongodb using java code. Please help.

Comment: You want only `chapters` list sorted order according to `dateUpload` is right?

Answer (score 2):

Mongo **[$aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)** will solve your problem. Below query first [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) your `chapters` array and then sort `dateUpload`

```
    db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$unwind": "$chapters" // unwind breaks the chapters array
}, {
    "$sort": {
    "chapters.dateUpload": -1 // then seperated chapters array sorted by dateUpload
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "chapters": {
        "$push": "$chapters" // group used for grouping chapters array
    }
    }
}).pretty()
```

And for converting above query in java code formatt then follow below mongo aggregation java driver code .
[Java Driver and Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, using [`aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```
db.foo.aggregate( [ { $project: {chapters: 1} },
                    { $unwind: "$chapters" },
                    { $sort: {"chapters.dateUpload": -1} }
                  ] );
```

Extract the chapters subdocument with [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), then [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) it to deconstruct the array and get each element, finally [`$sort`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) them on dateUpload value (descending, use `1` for ascending order).